# Text disappears in GUI while printing in separate thread

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qthread

In my code I have additional thread for printing:

```
class PrintThread : public QThread {
public:
    PrintThread(const QString& text, QPrinter* printer): mText(text), mPrinter(printer) {}
    void run()
    {
        QTextDocument doc;
        doc.setHtml(mText);
        doc.print(mPrinter);
        delete mPrinter;
    }
private:
    QString mText;
    QPrinter *mPrinter;
};
```

Separate thread is needed to prevent GUI from freezing when printing to pdf.
Sometimes during printing I see such lines in console (many times repeated):

> X Error: RenderBadGlyphSet (invalid GlyphSet parameter) 165
>
> Extension: 148 (RENDER)
>
> Minor opcode: 25 (RenderCompositeGlyphs32)
>
> Resource id: 0×0

And any text in GUI disappears. What the problem and how to solve it? Thanks.

I'm using Qt 4.4.3
Thread is created here:

```
void MyClass::print() {
    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter;
    printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
    QPrintDialog dialog(printer);
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QString text = dataForPrint();
        mPrintThread = new PrintThread(text, printer);
        connect(mPrintThread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onPrintingFinished()));
        mPrintThread->start();
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried your code on Qt 4.8 with Qt Creator on Windows, and it seems to work. I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you have, however I read this in the "Thread support in Qt modules" section of the Qt documentation:

> Note that on X11 systems without FontConfig support, Qt cannot render text outside of the GUI thread. You can use the QFontDatabase::supportsThreadedFontRendering() function to detect whether or not font rendering can be used outside the GUI thread.

Is it possible you're running into this problem?

Comment: QFontDatabase::supportsThreadedFontRendering() returns true. After few hours of googling I think that this issue belongs to Qt 4.4.3 and not to any newer versions...